# Accord du participe passé avec inversion du sujet

Tags: accord, participe-passé

Est-ce que l'accord du participe passé avec l'auxiliaire avoir se fait quand il y a une inversion du sujet ?

> - Les dates d'examen qu'ont programmé(es) les professeurs.
> - Les maisons qu'ont construit(es) les maçons.

Comment: Pourquoi l'inversion du sujet devrait-elle changer l'accord, qui est avec le COD dans le cas du verbe _avoir_?

Answer (score 3):

L'accord du participe passé avec l'auxiliaire "avoir" ne dépend pas directement de l'inversion du sujet, mais plutôt de la position du complément d'objet direct (*COD*) par rapport à celle du verbe.

Si le *COD* est placé avant le participe passé dans la phrase, alors le participe passé s'accord en genre et en nombre avec ce *COD*. Dans le cas contraire, le participe passé reste invariant.

Pour revenir à ton exemple: "les dates d'examens" et "les maisons" sont des *COD* qui sont placés avant le participe passé ("programmé" et "construit"), qui doit être accordé en conséquence.

L'inversion du sujet (i.e. inversion de l'ordre habituel sujet-verbe, avec "les professeurs" et "les maçons" venant après le verbe) n'affecte pas la règle d'accord dans ces exemples.

J'espère que cela vous aidera!

Comment: Le COD est le pronom relatif *que* dans les deux exemples. Ses antécédents (dont il est nécessaire de déterminer genre+nb.) ont très probablement une fonction *autre* que COD; sans supplément de contexte nous ne pouvons la connaître.

Comment: Merci.
Je trouve qui confirme votre réponse cet exemple chez Stendhal : « On se figure les belles choses qu’ont dites sur son compte les gens qui sont venus » (Histoire de la peinture en Italie, chapitre CLXXI)